# Setting imported material icon as a background in jss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a React-mui draggable dialog component on which I am using resizable box.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  resizable: {
    position: "relative",
    "& .react-resizable-handle": {
      position: "absolute",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      background:
        "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDYiIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiNmZmZmZmYwMCIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNnB4Ij48ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMwMiI+PHBhdGggZD0iTSA2IDYgTCAwIDYgTCAwIDQuMiBMIDQgNC4yIEwgNC4yIDQuMiBMIDQuMiAwIEwgNiAwIEwgNiA2IEwgNiA2IFoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+')",
      "background-position": "bottom right",
      padding: "0 3px 3px 0",
      "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
      "background-origin": "content-box",
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      cursor: "se-resize"
    }
  }
});

return (
    <StyledDialog
      open={open}
      classes={{root: classes.dialog, paper: classes.paper}}
      PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
      aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog"
    >
      <ResizableBox
        height={520}
        width={370}
        minConstraints={[300, 500]}
        maxConstraints={[Infinity, Infinity]}
        className={classes.resizable}
      >
        <DialogContent classes={{root: classes.dialogContent}} id="draggable-dialog">
          <IconButton className={classes.clearIcon} aria-label="Clear" onClick={onClose}>
            <ClearIcon/>
          </IconButton>
          <iframe
            src={hjelpemiddel.url}
            title={hjelpemiddel.navn}
            width="100%"
            height="500px">
          </iframe>
        </DialogContent>
      </ResizableBox>
    </StyledDialog>
  );
}
```

I would like to use my own icon instead of the default image used for the ResizableBox. How can I set the icon that I am importing from material icons as background of resizable?

```
import ZoomOutMapIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ZoomOutMap';
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI is using SVG for the ZoomOutMapIcon. What I would do is convert that SVG to base64 then apply that to the background-url

[image]

This is its base64 output: `PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0iTXVpU3ZnSWNvbi1yb290IiBmb2N1c2FibGU9ImZhbHNlIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgYXJpYS1oaWRkZW49InRydWUiID48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTUgM2wyLjMgMi4zLTIuODkgMi44NyAxLjQyIDEuNDJMMTguNyA2LjcgMjEgOVYzaC02ek0zIDlsMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg3IDIuODkgMS40Mi0xLjQyTDYuNyA1LjMgOSAzSDN2NnptNiAxMmwtMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg5LTIuODctMS40Mi0xLjQyTDUuMyAxNy4zIDMgMTV2Nmg2em0xMi02bC0yLjMgMi4zLTIuODctMi44OS0xLjQyIDEuNDIgMi44OSAyLjg3TDE1IDIxaDZ2LTZ6Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+`

and I usually use `makeStyles` for overriding CSS when using Material UI

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  resizable: {
    position: "relative",
    "& .react-resizable-handle": {
      position: "absolute",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      background:
        "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0iTXVpU3ZnSWNvbi1yb290IiBmb2N1c2FibGU9ImZhbHNlIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgYXJpYS1oaWRkZW49InRydWUiID48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTUgM2wyLjMgMi4zLTIuODkgMi44NyAxLjQyIDEuNDJMMTguNyA2LjcgMjEgOVYzaC02ek0zIDlsMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg3IDIuODkgMS40Mi0xLjQyTDYuNyA1LjMgOSAzSDN2NnptNiAxMmwtMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg5LTIuODctMS40Mi0xLjQyTDUuMyAxNy4zIDMgMTV2Nmg2em0xMi02bC0yLjMgMi4zLTIuODctMi44OS0xLjQyIDEuNDIgMi44OSAyLjg3TDE1IDIxaDZ2LTZ6Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+')",
      "background-position": "bottom right",
      padding: "0 3px 3px 0",
      "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
      "background-origin": "content-box",
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      cursor: "se-resize"
    }
  }
});

<ResizableBox
  className={classes.resizable}
>
```

[image: Edit wizardly-hopper-s3v9z]